物差し (ruler) - why 差す?
差す appears to have a lost of uses, most of which seem to involve making something pass through a point in space (and then, for lack of a better word, 'shoot out' from there) or the motions related to doing so. None of them seem to have anything to do with measurement though.
On the other hand it seems like the Kanji 差 is related to difference and subtraction which strikes me as much closer to the function of a ruler.
So why the 連用形 of 差す? And for that matter why after 物 unlike similar words such as 着物 or 買い物 (or even 指し物 :p)?

デジタル大辞泉 has a definition for 差す specifically for this situation: 物差しで寸法を測る。「縦横の寸法を—・してみた」〈三重吉・桑の実〉("to measure the size (of something) with a ruler").

@Axe oh cool, I guess I was hoping for something more general but that makes sense! I wonder if that meaning comes from the Kanji in the  + す sort of construction or if it's the same さす as the other meanings.

If your question is not about the verb choice but about the verb form, please read this first: Conjunctive form (e.g. 書き) vs Conj + mono (e.g. 書き物)
In particular, turning a verb into the masu-stem (連用形) has a similar effect to adding "-er/-or" to an English verb. Similar words formed this way include:

はかり (weight) scale
ねじ回し screwdriver
カビ取り mold killer
栓抜き (lit. plug puller) → bottle opener / corkscrew
洗濯ばさみ (lit. laundry clamper) → clothespin
虫取り網 (lit. bug-catching net) → insect net

Likewise, 物差し refers to a tool used to measure things (物).

It was both, but I guess I really should have posted two separate questions. This is great though, thanks! If I'm understanding correctly, based on the order 物差し is probably closer to "thing measurer" than "measurement thing" then?

@acumandr Yes, that's it. As for the verb choice, 差す has too many uses, but I think the base meaning is "to extend one's arm to do something". Maybe something like "thing specifier" is a more literal translation.
